# Jquery: how to get menu to expand towards the right instead of the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to get this menu to expand towards the right instead of the left, not exactly sure how to do it as I can't find what in the CSS is making it expand towards the left. Any thoughts? thanks a lot!

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/24/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was this what you were aiming for?
http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/28/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/28/

```
$('.menu ul li:has("ul")').each(function(){
   var nameWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
       dropdownWidth = $(this).find('ul').width(),
       change = (dropdownWidth - nameWidth) - 10;
    $(this).find('ul').css('left', change+'px');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I need the drop down menu box containing the link "Reader Reader" to expand towards the right instead of the left. Not have the menu links float to the right. Thanks

Comment: Updated it to what you were looking for.